# How to change a number into a letter?

Tags: c, linux

I'm making a game for a game of poker and currently have an array of 52 cards
`int cards[52] = {1, 1, 1, 1, etc etc etc...}`

However, I want it so that every time that a 1 appears or an 11 or a 12 or a 13 for a letter to appear like A, J, Q and K instead of those numbers.

I currently have part of my code (still not finished) but kept doing everything with the array of 1,2,3,4,5,6..., 13 so I would prefer not having to restart since the beginning.

P.S.: I'm currently quite new to programming so explaining like a beginner would help a lot!!

P.S.: The problem is I'm not sure how to do this

for one of my sub-functions

```
for (l = 0; l < 52; l++) //For loop del swap para barajear la baraja
{
    x = rand() % 52;
    y = rand() % 52;
    int temp = cards[x];
    cards[x] = cards[y];
    cards[y] = temp;
    char *temp1 = symbols[x];
    symbols[x] = symbols[y];
    symbols[y] = temp1;
}
```

How can I make it so that if I print `cards[1]` and the value of `cards[1]` after being swapped is `1`, how can I make it so that it prints `'A'` instead of `1`

Comment: use a `char` array: `char c[] = "A23456789JKQ"`?

Comment: @raser Suspect you wanted 13 `char` rather than 12: `"A23456789XJKQ"`  (missing 10)

Comment: a char array is a good ideea. also remember that cards are not only numbers, they are also colors: Ad, As, Ac, Ah, 2d, 2s, 2c, 2h etc. you may want to have 4 different arrays, one for each color. i also suggest using another programming language, since you are trying to do high level stuff, and you can get a lot more done with less code. also, you will find some useful containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array `letters` to store the card names.  You can then access the array using `letters[card]`.

As a shorthand, you can write the individual `char` values as one string:

```
char letters[] = "XA234567890BDK";
```

Note that index of the first letter will automatically be zero.  If you want the card “two” to be the index `2`, you will have to fill the first place with a dummy character.

---

Considering your second problem (shuffling), you can omit the array `symbols` completely.  Just look up the associated symbol from `letters` when you actually need it.

Comment: Sorry for the nooby question but how can i access the array and then replace the value I have as int cards into the char ones?

Comment: This could, for example, be `letter = letters[card];`.

Comment: how can i implement that on something like this
 for (l = 0; l < 52; l++) //For loop del swap para barajear la baraja
 {
  x = rand() % 52;
  y = rand() % 52;
  int temp = cards[x];
  cards[x] = cards[y];
  cards[y] = temp;
  char *temp1 = symbols[x];
  symbols[x] = symbols[y];
  symbols[y] = temp1;
 }

Like how to make it so that when i print cards[1] and the value of it is 1, to show an A

Comment: Hmm I used a different array as someone mentioned here for char *letters[13] = {"A", etc etc.} but the problem is that all of these do appear except for the letter A for some odd reason.

Comment: *Note that index of the first letter will automatically be zero.*  So if you don't use `0` as a card index but start with `1` (which you reasonably may have chosen to do), prepend something arbitrary which will be used as the character for the (non-existent) card number zero.  `char *letters[13] = {"X", "A", etc etc.}` should do.

Comment: wouldn't my array then need to be of char*letters [14]? 
I mean for some odd reason I do get all of the letters and numbers except for A

and since i made my print to be letters[card[o]] o with a for loop

Comment: Oops…  Sure, it has to be `letters[13]`.  Actually, you don't need the number at all—the only purpose it has (and the only reason to include it) is to prevent you from accidentally changing the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just use another array.

```
char ranks[] = { 0, 'A', '2', '3', ..., 'J', 'Q', 'K'};
```

And then access it as normal.

Comment: The problem is im using a swap and bubble sort for the hand which is a straight and idk if using chars can help me with that... Also how can you input 10 as a single char? :o

Comment: Okay, array of `char*` if you like. Still the same deal. And you don't access the array until output.

Comment: Maybe you'll hate me for this but how can i access it until the output? *-*...
I mean what if in my function i have something that calls for a cards[1] and the value of cards[1] after swapping, bubble sorting or whatever is 1 or 10 or 11, etc. 
How can i make it so that when i call it out into a printf, i call out an 'A' instead of a 1.

Comment: `printf("%c of whatever\n", ranks[card]);`

Comment: OHH I see!
This doesn't matter if my original cards array is of [52]?
Meaning that I would only have to change the printf(%d) -> printf("%s") that i had?
Thanks a lot!
Also, I seem to get a problem when using %c, The J,Q,K,X appear but for some reason the A doesnt appear

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
char card_names[] = { 'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'K', 'Q' };
```

Then you can use `card_names[card_value]`.

Comment: The problem is im using a swap and bubble sort for the hand which is a straight and idk if using chars can help me with that... Also how can you input 10 as a single char? :o

Comment: You only use card names when doing input or output. The rest of the code should work with values, and that's what you should sort.